# Is it possible to chunk file uploads in angular?

Tags: angular, file-upload, upload

The current app that I have built uploads a video file into memory before processing them. I was wondering if it is possible to upload these files by chunking them in Angular 5, and if so what are the possible solutions to doing so.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#upload-service

Comment: @artm Isn't that an AngularJS library?